# UITableViewCell dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier returns the same cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am creating a UITableView that enables the user to add a variable amount of data. Table looks like this initially:

[image]

When the user clicks on the "+" button, i would like to add a new cell with a UITextField for entering data. This new cell is a Custom UITableViewCell called "RecordValueCell". Here's what is looks like:

[image]

```
//Custom UITableViewCell
class RecordValueCell : UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var deleteButton: UIButton!

    var onButtonTapped : ((_ sender : UIButton)->Void)?

    @IBAction func deleteButtonTouched(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let senderButton = sender as? UIButton else {
            return
        }
        onButtonTapped?(senderButton)
    }
}
```

However when i try to add another cell, using the `tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: )` function, it seems to return the same cell. And here is what my UI looks like:

[image]

Empty space at the top of the section where my new cell should be. Here is the code to add the cell:

```
func addNewValueCell() {
    guard let reusableValueCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "valueCell") as? RecordValueCell else {
        fatalError("failed to get reusable cell valueCell")
    }

    var cell = Cell() //some custom cell Object
    //add the gray horizontal line you see in the pictures
    reusableValueCell.textField.addBorder(toSide: .Bottom, withColor: UIColor.gray.cgColor, andThickness: 0.5)

    reusableValueCell.onButtonTapped = { (sender) in
        self.removeValue(sender: sender)
    }

    cell.cell = reusableValueCell
    self.sections[self.sections.count - 1].cells.insert(cell, at: 0)

    //When i put a break point at this spot, i find that reusableValueCell is the same object as the cell that is already being used.
    tableView.reloadData()

    reusableValueCell.prepareForReuse()
}
```

When i debug it, i find that `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: )` returns the exact same RecordValueCell multiple times.

Here is my `cellForRowAt`:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = self.sections[indexPath.section].cells[indexPath.row].cell else {
        fatalError("error getting cell")
    }

    return cell
}
```

`numberOfRowsInSection`

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.sections[section].cells.count
}
```

Comment: You should dequeue only in cellForRow, and yes cells are reused, that’s the whole point.

Comment: If you want to insert a new row you need to change the value returned by `numberOfRowsInSection` and call `insertRow`. The additional cell will then be dequeued in `cellForRowAt`

Comment: @matt my `addNewValueCell()` function is called every time the '+' button is pressed, thats why i dequeue there. Does it matter what function i dequeue?

Comment: @Paulw11 my `cellForRowAt` is always accurate (look at the edit). The cell gets added as expected, just happens to not be visible even if the space exists (3rd Image).

Comment: No,that isn't how you implement `cellForRowAt` - You should dequeue a reusable cell in that function and configure it.  You can't just pull a cell from an array of cells you prepared earlier.  Your data model can 't be an array of cells.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will need to set the View Controller Class that this table is contained in as the table's [UITableViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource)

```
tableView.dataSource = self // view controller that contains the tableView
```

Create an array of strings as member of your View Controller class which contains the data for each cell:

`var strings = [String]()`

Then you will need to implement the following method for the UITableViewDataSource protocol:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return strings.count
}
```

You should also be dequeueing the cells in your cellForRowAt method like so:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: yourIdentifier) as! YourCellClass
    cell.textLabel = strings[indexPath.row]
    return cell   
}
```

Then whenever the user enters into the textField, their input will be appended to this array:

`let input = textField.text
strings.append(input)
tableView.reloadData()`

Once the data is reloaded, the cell will be added to the table automatically since the number of rows are defined by the String array's length and the label is set in the cellForRowAt method.

Comment: The is a `UITableViewController` so the datasource and delegate are already set. I have included the `numberOfRowsInSection` function. please take a look.  My `numberOfRowsInSection` function seems to return the right number of rows. So i don't think that is the problem

Comment: I would suggest letting the `UITableViewController` manage the cells instead of making an array of cells that you need to manage yourself. You should be dequeuing the cells in `cellForRowAt` rather than when the user input is pressed. If I were to guess why you are getting the same cell dequeued everytime from your code it is because you are never setting the `UILabel` in the cell to the before you return it.

Answer (score -2):

This feature is very easy to implement if you will do in a good way.

First, you have to create two TableCell. First to give the option to add a record with plus button and second for entering a value with textfield. Now always return first cell (AddRecordTableCell) in the last row in tableView, and return the number of rows according to entered values like

return totalValues.count + 1